# How do I implement an EJS template in PUG?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, ejs

Can someone help me convert this EJS code to PUG? I'm trying to learn PUG and I'd like to implement this piece of code; it's for pagination. Everything works fine in EJS but I haven't quite grasped how to write  conditionals and loops in PUG just yet . Below is a snippet of the code:

```
</div>
  <% if (pages > 0) { %>
      <ul class="pagination text-center">
          <% if (current == 1) { %>
              <li class="disabled"><a>First</a></li>
          <% } else { %>
              <li><a href="/products/1">First</a></li>
          <% } %>
          <% var i = (Number(current) > 5 ? Number(current) - 4 : 1) %>
          <% if (i !== 1) { %>
              <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
          <% } %>
          <% for (; i <= (Number(current) + 4) && i <= pages; i++) { %>
              <% if (i == current) { %>
                  <li class="active"><a><%= i %></a></li>
              <% } else { %>
                  <li><a href="/products/<%= i %>"><%= i %></a></li>
              <% } %>
              <% if (i == Number(current) + 4 && i < pages) { %>
                  <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
              <% } %>
          <% } %>
          <% if (current == pages) { %>
              <li class="disabled"><a>Last</a></li>
          <% } else { %>
              <li><a href="/products/<%= pages %>">Last</a></li>
          <% } %>
      </ul>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

All research I've done point me to either HTML to EJS or HTML to PUG, or vice versa. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, in either English or pseudocode?

Comment: It's for pagination. I just edited the question to include the whole code snippet

Comment: Conditionals and iteration are really easy in pug, and are [well documented](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html) too.  Do you have a specific question about it?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I get the conditionals bit. However, the iterators are my headache. The documentation doesn't have enough examples for me to follow along. All I see are the forEach equivalents. How do I write, say, `for (let i = 1; i <= rating; i++)` without running into an error

Comment: Well, now we're back where we started.  Take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the StackOverflow help section.

Comment: Have you also checked out all of the examples in the [search history](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpug%5D+ejs)?